# Cyclic vectors of diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

So I recently covered cyclic vectors but don't seem to fully understand how they work. I am supposed to find all the cyclic vectors of a transformation $T=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, and when it doesn't have any.

As far as I can see, for $v\in V^n$ to be a cyclic vector we must have that the set $\{v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots,T^{n-1}v\}$ is linearly independent and spans $V$. Since $T$ is diagonal, however, we have that $T^k=\text{diag}(\lambda_1^k,\lambda_2^k,\ldots,\lambda_n^k)$. Once I get here I am not really sure how to proceed and find whether this vector is cyclic or if there are any such vectors. Are there any sources or theorems someone may point me to so I can learn how I can solve these types of problems? Thanks!

Comment: First thing: when you say "as far as I can see, v is a cyclic...", do you mean "the definition of a cyclic vector is"... Or do you have a doubt ?

Comment: Hint: minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots,T^{n-1}v\}$ are independent if and only if:

$$\tag{1}a_0v+a_1Tv+a_2T^2v+\ldots+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=0 \ \ \implies \ \ \forall k, a_k=0  \ $$

which is equivalent to:

$$\tag{2}\underbrace{(a_0+a_1T+a_2T^2+\ldots+a_{n-1}T^{n-1})}_{U=diag(p(\lambda_1),\cdots,p(\lambda_n))}v=0 \ \ \implies \ \ \forall k, a_k=0 $$

where

$$p(x):=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}.$$

If we denote by $v_k$ the coefficients of $v$, (2) is equivalent to:

$\tag{3}\begin{pmatrix}p(\lambda_1)v_1\\
\vdots \\ p(\lambda_n)v_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
\vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

> **If all $\lambda_k$s are distinct** and **all $v_k$ are non zero**, then $ \ \ \ $ (*)

(3) expresses that $p$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ with $n$ distinct roots. This is not possible unless it is the null polynomial, i.e., all its coefficients $a_k$s are zero, as desired (see the objective of (1)).

> Thus, under conditions (*) above, $v$ is a cyclic vector.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful in making sense of how I may approach this type of problem.